# How to receive arrays sent by Ajax in a .jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Hi I wrote the below js code to send two arrays to a jsp file

```
$.post("scriptlet.jsp",
{ sg: array1[], st: array2[] },
function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
}
);
```

How do I retrieve them form the jsp side? I tried doing this inside scriptlet.jsp . But didn't work

```
<%
    String[] questionsList = (String)request.getParameter("sg");
%>
```

Comment: is the `array1[]` has as type `String` ??

Comment: Sorry for the typo I tried doing them too. But didn't work

Comment: yes it has type string @PacMan

Comment: Busines logic in jsp file. This is madness.

Comment: @krishmandava `{ sg: array1[], st: array2[] }` should be `{ sg: array1, st: array2 }` and `String[] questionsList = (String)request.getParameter("sg");` should be `String[] questionsList = (String[])request.getParameter("sg");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand very well your problem , so you are trying to send JavaScript array to a `jsp` page , so here are my suggestion :

```
<script >
var tab = ["hello","world"]; //here is an array for test
$.get("scriptlet.jsp",{ sg:tab  },function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<% 

String[] myArray = request.getParameterValues("sg[]");
out.println(myArray[0]); // this will print you  "hello"
%>

</body>
```